# Overfull hbox too wide

Tags: spacing

```
Overfull \hbox (13.50009pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 149-157.

149 \begin{tabular}{rl}
151  Basic Knowledge:& \textsc{C}, \textsc{Python}, \textsc{html}, ubuntu, \\&
152 {\fb \LaTeX}\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Fontin-SmallCaps.otf]{Fontin.otf}\\
152 Intermediate Knowledge:& \textsc{Fritzing, EAGLE}, Embedded C, Excel, Word, PowerPoint, 154 MATLAB\\
155 & and Simulink\\


156\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Did you have a question? Note that you can display code by indenting by 4 spaces. The easiest is to select the code and use the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Your cell has a `setmainfont` command, is that intended? Furthermore, what is \fb?

Comment: Please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem. As of now, it's difficult to see what could cause this. A paragraph indent? Perhaps too wide of a line that doesn't wrap within a cell?

Answer (score 2):

Eliminating various (probably irrelevant) font material, your code is

```
\begin{tabular}{rl}
Basic Knowledge:       & \textsc{C}, \textsc{Python}, \textsc{html}, ubuntu, \\
                       & \LaTeX\\
Intermediate Knowledge:& \textsc{Fritzing, EAGLE}, Embedded C, Excel, Word,
                         PowerPoint, MATLAB\\
                       & and Simulink\\
\end{tabular}
```

There's a bunch of problems here. Fundamentally you simply have too much text in the second column: you need either to use columtype `p` and set a width for that, or (better) use `tabularx` and let LaTeX find an appropriate width. Having done that, you won't need to try to break lines yourself (as you have with "and Simulink") which is the sort of layout decision that we aim to avoid.

Something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX}
Basic Knowledge:       & C, \textsc{Python}, \textsc{html}, ubuntu, \LaTeX\\
Intermediate Knowledge:& \textsc{Fritzing}, EAGLE, Embedded C, Excel, Word,
                          PowerPoint, MATLAB and Simulink
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

More fundamentally, however, a table is probably not really the right way of presenting this sort of information. It's really a description list, and it would be wiser to present it as such. You can always use a package like `enumitem` to adjust how this looks, if you are not happy with the standard format.